# Element 1 has a CSS top of x% and height of y%. Element 2 has a CSS top of (x+y)%. Why do the pixel values differ?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a sizing issue here.

**Summary of what I'm trying to achieve**

I'm using the resizable and draggable functionality as well as some JS code to set the top, left, height, and width of the elements on the screen. I want to be able to resize an element until it collides with another element. If the element being resized collides with another element it should be flush i.e. the elements should be touching with no gap in between.

**The sizing issue that I'm seeing**

When I resize an element, it stops resizing when it collides with the other element. Everything seems fine but sometimes a small gap appears between the elements (usually less than a pixel big).
When I calculate the top + height of the first element, to get its bottom, it seems to match the top of the second element, as expected e.g. if element 1's top = 10%, element 1's height = 10%, then element 2's top equals 20%. Perfect!

But then I calculate the pixel values and see the following:

```
Element1.offset().top + Element1.height() != Element2.offset().top
```

**Example of issue with screenshots**

I want to know why the percentages do not match the corresponding pixel values. I've included an example below, with pictures attached, to illustrate my issue.

Element 1 (above element):

```
Top + Height = Bottom

13.64% + 13.68% = 27.32%
```

[Element 1 and its percentage top and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVwdJ.png)

Element 2 (below element):

```
Top = 27.32%
```

[Element 2 and its percentage top and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GjTE.png)

As seen above, the top plus height of element 1 equals the top of element 2. But look what happens when I calculate the same values in pixels:

```
Element1.offset().top + Element1.height() = 175.5875015258789px

Element2.offset().top = 175.60000610351562px
```

[Pixel values of top + height of Element1 vs top of Element2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLqgG.png)

Why does Element1.offset().top + Element1.height() not equal Element2.offset().top if the percentage values are the same?

[Here's a link to the JSFiddel demo of the software](https://jsfiddle.net/vrom25wt/)

Comment: in a place you have 27.23 and in the other 27.32

Comment: Consider posting a minimum reproducible demo.

Comment: It's due to rounding errors when working in relative units. If you need to-the-pixel precision, don't use %.

Comment: @vals thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've been instructed to use percentages by my manager. This is to enable resizing of elements when minimizing/resizing the window. Is there an alternative option?

Comment: I'd suggest using [FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see... You're referring to using a flexbox instead of percentages. I'm designing a UI to allow users to drag and drop elements in order to design custom dashboards.
So the user needs to resize all elements how they want and in all directions (n,s,e,w). They also have to be able to rearrange elements and resize them.

Would using flex box work in this case?

Comment: @NisanthReddy I just added the JSFiddel code to the bottom of my post. Would you mind checking it out?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just added the JSFiddel code to the bottom of my post. Would you mind checking it out?

Comment: Code should be on this site. See [ask]. You can likely use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to produce a [mre] of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your border that is the problem. **css**

```
* {border-style: none;}
```